# Xcode 5.0.1 crash on OS X Mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I am unable to start the Xcode 5.0.1 after update to OS X Mavericks. Please help.

Here is the message from crash report:

`Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A2053
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for key 'delegateClass' of extension 'Xcode.RepositoriesViewer.MenuDefinition.HelpContextualMenu' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.IDERepositoryViewer'
UserInfo: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x7ff8bf440f10 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.IDERepositoryViewer, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDERepositoryViewer.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDERepositoryViewer, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDERepositoryViewer.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.IDE.IDERepositoryViewer\U201d at path \U201c/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDERepositoryViewer.ideplugin\U201d could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff8bf43c8e0 \"The bundle \U201cIDERepositoryViewer\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";`

Comment: Please make sure you file a radar on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it this way:

go to

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns
```

and remove the following directory (maybe you should backup first)

```
IDERepositoryViewer.ideplugin
```

After this I am able to start and work with Xcode. Maybe this solution has some limitation, but I did not see any at this time.

Comment: LOL.  (sing along now) "There may be trouble ahead..."

Comment: strange errors -> strange solutions ... look, I am able to complete my tasks again, so it is good for now until the next Xcode update (hopefully will be fixed)

Comment: Thanks for the hand, though I moved it instead of deleting it.

Comment: i don't have that plugin, it might be outdated

Comment: This happened to me after installing xcode 5.0.2 (was 5.0.1). Renaming IDERepositoryView as suggested worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded a dual-Xcode system to Xcode 5.0.2 this morning.  I had Xcode 4.6.3 in /Applications named "Xcode" and Xcode 5.0 named as "Xcode5".  After the upgrade, I only had "Xcode" and it crashed on launch with the same error from IDERepositoryViewer.ideplugin

Looking into the plugin's version.plist file, I see key "CFBundleShortVersionString" with value "4.6.3", so I presume it kept the plugin from Xcode 4.6.3 somehow.

Once I deleted it, Xcode 5.0.2 worked fine.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to check Build path.

Comment: follow these steps. Xcode > Preferences > Source Control > Uncheck the Enable Source control .

Comment: I could try this, because I am able to start the Xcode now. But without deleting this Plugin I was unable to start Xcode and therefore unable to go to Preferences window.

Comment: Doesn't work. I was able to start Xcode after I moved the plugin out, then I uncheched version control, moved the plugin back in and Xcode crashed.